# Is there a way to get diff between two JSON objects in Java?

Tags: java, json, diff

```
{"monitors":[{"name": "Dummy","threshold": 155},{"name": "Dummy1","threshold": 321}]}
{"monitors":[{"name": "Dummy","threshold": 215},{"name": "Dummy1","threshold": 341}]}
```

So basically I want to get the JSON fields that differ in values. I there an API in Java that could do that.

I want output as something like code diff that we see in Git or any other VCs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17812/java-library-that-diffs-json-and-generates-what-was-added-deleted-modified

Comment: Well, was looking for a simpler method. Btw thanks a lot for sharing. Will try to go with this one :)